# showing results on the same page flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to show search results on the same page.When a users searchs that input is posted to a route dashboard and that route returns JSON object.How can i show those results in materialize cards?I am trying to use AJAX and jquery.

```
@app.route('/dash',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    form=searchDashBoard(request.form)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            user_input = form.wineName.data
            similar=a.getClosestMatch(user_input)[:9]
            if not similar:
                flash(' Wine Not found ')
            else:
                newList=[]
                for id in similar:
                    print(id)
                    info= a.getWineInfo(id)
                    r=requests.get('https://www.vivino.com/api/wines/'+str(id)+'/wine_page_information').json()
                    pic_url = r['wine_page_information']['vintage']['image']['location']
                    info['url']="https:"+str(pic_url)
                    newList.append(info)
                return jsonify(newList)
    return render_template('dashboard.html',name=current_user.username,form=form)
```

ajax

When the searchBtn is clicked it gets the data from a route /dash and then loop throught and create cards.So basically i want to output something like the searchCard.html but on the same page as where i have the seachinput and button.

```
    $('#searchBtn').click,(function(){
  $.getJSON('/dash',function(obj){
    $.each(obj,function(key,value){
      $('ul').append('<li>'+value.id+'</li>')

    })

  })
}
```

searchcard.html

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
{% for w in newList %}
  <ul class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item avatar">
        <img src={{ w['url'] }} style="max-height: 100px" alt="wine Image" class="circle">
        <span class="title">{{w['name']}}</span>
        <p><i class="material-icons">location_on</i> {{ w['region'] }}
        </p>
        <p> <i class="material-icons">attach_money</i> {{ w['price'] }}</p>
        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons addBtn" wineID="{{ w['id'] }}" >add</i></a>
      </li>
</ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something funky is going on with your brackets here:

```
 $.ajax("{{url_for('save') "}}.done(function(reply){
```

Change it to:

```
 $.ajax("{{ url_for('save') }}").done(function(reply){
```

Look in your browser console for hints though, we can't do too much here without knowing exactly what error is occurring.

Comment: So basically what i want to do is user search for a wine that input is posted in a flask route and that route returns a JSON object i just wanted to show the content of json object in a materialize cards